# Help understanding system and package dependencies with rosbuild and catkin

Tags: ros, rosdep, catkin, dependencies, rospack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed ros-hydro-desktop-full and a few other packages on Ubuntu 12.04.  The package ros-hydro-urdf is installed, but the package ros-hydro-cmake-modules is not.  The urdf package has a <build_depend>cmake_modules</build_depend> entry in its package.xml file.

I am trying to understand how "rosdep check" and "rospack depends" behave with the various types of dependencies available in rosbuild and catkin packages, and how these dependencies are related to the dependencies between debian packages in Ubuntu.  I have performed the following tests, which have given rise to several questions.

**Test 1: catkin package with <build_depend>cmake_modules</build_depend>**

```
  # rosdep check: detects dependency
  $ rosdep check example_package
  System dependencies have not been satisified:
  apt   ros-hydro-cmake-modules

  # rospack depends: misses dependency
  $ rospack depends example_package
  (nothing)
```

- Question 1a: Why doesn't rospack detect this dependency?
- Question 1b: Does rospack only care about <run_depend> entries for catkin packages?
- Question 1c: Is rospack supposed to work properly with catkin packages?

**Test 2: catkin package with <run_depend>cmake_modules</run_depend>**

```
  # rosdep check: detects dependency
  $ rosdep check example_package
  System dependencies have not been satisified:
  apt   ros-hydro-cmake-modules

  # rospack depends: generates error
  $ rospack depends example_package
  [rospack] Error: package/stack 'example_package' depends on non-existent package 'cmake_modules' and rosdep claims that it is not a system dependency. Check the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH or try calling 'rosdep update'
```

- Question 2a: Why does rospack not detect this dependency?
- Question 2b: Why does rospack generate an error?
- Question 2c: Why does rospack say that rosdep does not recognise cmake_modules as a system dependency?  It is included in the rosdep definitions.

**Test 3: catkin package with <build_depend>urdf</build_depend>**

```
  # rosdep check: fails (misses dependency)
  $ rosdep check example_package
  All system dependencies have been satisified

  # rospack depends: misses dependency
  $ rospack depends example_package
  (nothing)
```

- Question 3: Shouldn't both rosdep and rospack handle such recursive dependencies?  The urdf package depends on the cmake_modules package.

**Test 4: catkin package with <run_depend>urdf</run_depend>**

```
  # rosdep check: misses dependency
  $ rosdep check example_package
  All system dependencies have been satisified

  # rospack depends: misses dependency
  $ rospack depends example_package | grep cmake_modules
  (nothing)
```

**Test 5: rosbuild package with <rosdep name="cmake_modules" />**

```
  # rosdep check: detects dependency
  $ rosdep check example_package
  System dependencies have not been satisified:
  apt   ros-hydro-cmake-modules

  # rospack depends: misses dependency
  $ rospack depends example_package
  (nothing)
```

**Test 6: rosbuild package with <depend package="cmake_modules" />**

```
  # rosdep check: misses dependency and generates error
  $ rosdep check example_package
  All system dependencies have been satisified
  ERROR[example_package]: resource not found [cmake_modules]

  # rospack depends: generates error
  $ rospack depends example_package
  [rospack] Error: package/stack 'example_package' depends on non-existent package 'cmake_modules' and rosdep claims that it is not a system dependency. Check the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH or try calling 'rosdep update'
```

- Question 6a: Why do rosdep and rospack fail?  Isn't cmake_modules a ROS package, which one should be able to specify as a package dependency?
- Question 6b: What does rosdep's "resource not found" error mean?

**Test 7: rosbuild package with <rosdep name="urdf" />**

```
  # rosdep check: misses dependency
  $ rosdep check example_package
  All system dependencies have been satisified

  # rospack depends: misses dependency
  $ rospack depends example_package
  (nothing)
```

**Test 8: rosbuild package with <depend package="urdf" />**

```
  # rosdep check: misses dependency and generates error
  $ rosdep check example_package
  All system dependencies have been satisified
  ERROR[example_package]: resource not found [cmake_modules]

  # rospack depends: misses dependency
  $ rospack depends example_package | grep cmake_modules
  (nothing)
```

**Test 9: apt-cache**

```
  # ros-hydro-urdf: misses dependency
  apt-cache depends ros-hydro-urdf | grep cmake-modules
  (nothing)
```

- Question 9a: Why doesn't ros-hydro-urdf not depend on ros-hydro-cmake-modules?
- Question 9b: Do debian dependencies only use <run_depend> entries for catkin packages?
- Question 9c: What is the relationship between debian dependencies and the <depend> and <rosdep> entries in rosbuild package manifest.xml files?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/84616/help-understanding-system-and-package-dependencies-with-rosbuild-and-catkin/) by [leblanc_kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1052/leblanc_kevin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 357 on 2013-09-28

Post score: 14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to clarify the terms first:

- *build dependencies* (http://ros.org/reps/rep-0127.html#build-depend-multiple) are things a package needs in order to be build
- *run dependencies* (http://ros.org/reps/rep-0127.html#run-depend-multiple) are on the one hand things a package needs to be executed and on the other hand for transitive dependencies it provides to other package when they build against this package

Based on that I will first answer your questions *9a* and *9b* since they will be the foundation for understanding how dependencies of ROS packages map to Debian packages.

Only the *run dependencies* are used for the dependencies of the Debian packages. Since `ros-hydro-urdf` does not need `ros-hydro-cmake-modules` at runtime (but only at build time) it does not declare a run dependency on it. Therefore the Debian package `ros-hydro-urdf` does not depend on `ros-hydro-cmake-modules` which result in `ros-hydro-cmake-modules` not being installed automatically.

Short answers:

**9a:** Because the `urdf` package has no run dependency on `cmake_modules`.

**9b:** Yes, on the run dependencies are mapped to Debian dependencies.

--

The next topic will be rosdep:

Since system dependencies are named very differently on various platforms the rosdep database (stored in these files: https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/tree/master/rosdep) defines a mapping of names (called rosdep keys) to platform specific package names. For dependencies only these rosdep keys are used. In many cases they map 1to1 to Ubuntu packages names.

Besides these system packages there is also a known list of ROS packages. For wet the packages are listed in the rosdistro release file (https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/hydro/release.yaml), for dry stacks were the unit of packaging and they are listed in the equivalent legacy release file (https://code.google.com/p/ros-dry-releases/source/browse/trunk/distros/groovy.rosdistro#210). [Hydro does not have any released dry packages anymore.]

Now to the answer of question **9c:**

For wet packages dependencies on system packages and ROS packages are not specified differently. The tools will automatically figure out of the name is a ROS package or a rosdep key. For dry packages system dependencies are specified using the `rosdep` tag and dependencies on other ROS packages with the `depend` tag. For dry packages both type of dependencies - `rosdep` as well as `depend` - are used for the Debian packages - they do not differentiate between build and run dependencies. [E.g. for ROS packages the Debian package name starts with `ros-DISTRO-` which will automatically be added during the release process.]

--

**Test 1**

`rospack` needs to provide the necessary information to enable building *dry* packages on top of *wet* packages. Since the *dry* and *wet* world have very different concepts `rospack` does not look very consistent in its behavior. But most of it is necessary to provide support for building dry packages.

**1b:** Yes, rospack does only traverse the run dependencies.

Why is that the case. E.g. a dry package `D` depends on a wet package `W`. `W` itself build depends on `Wb` and run depends on `Wr`. Everything `D` cares about is that it needs `W` and `Wr` to build and run itself.

**1a:** Since cmake_modules is not a run dependency of example_package it is therefore not detected by rospack.

**1c:** Yes and no. I would say rospack fully supports the use cases of building dry on top of wet. But due to the complexity of that backward compatibility between both build systems the result does sometime look different from what the user would expect.

--

**Test 2**

First, your statement that "cmake_modules is included in the rosdep definitions" is not true. It is not listed in any of the rosdep files (https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/tree/master/rosdep) but only as a ROS package in the rosdistro release file (https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/hydro/release.yaml).

**2a:** `rospack` looks for a ROS package `cmake_modules` on your system (anywhere in the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH). Since it does not find the ROS package anywhere it complains that it is missing.

**2b:** After not finding a ROS package with that name `rospack` will query `rosdep` for a *rosdep key* `cmake_modules`. But since `rosdep` does not know that key either it generates an error message.

**2c:** The error message states "package/stack 'example_package' depends on non-existent package 'cmake_modules'" (because no ROS package with that name was found on your system) and "rosdep claims that it is not a system dependency" (since rosdep does not have a rosdep key with that name).

Then it suggests the following two potential fixes to the user:

- "Check the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH" in order to add a path where the ROS package can be found
- "try calling 'rosdep update'" in order to fetch a newer rosdep database in the case that cmake_modules has recently been added there as a system dependency

--

For the other tests:

`rosdep check` does not do a recursive check. It only makes sure that the dependencies of the given package are met. (To check direct (!) dependencies for multiple packages you can use the `--from-paths` option of rosdep.)

`rospack depends` only traverses run dependencies and therefore does not care about cmake_modules.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 12

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [leblanc_kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1052/leblanc_kevin/) on 2013-09-29**:
Thanks for the thorough and quick response!  Most of this confirms my suspicions, but I just couldn't wrap my mind around some of the things I was seeing compared to what I expected based on the documentation.

**Comment by [leblanc_kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1052/leblanc_kevin/) on 2013-09-29**:
I must say I'll be glad when rosbuild is gone: one less degree of freedom.  The ROS documentation and tools are lagging, and understandably.  Too many tools need to do slightly different things in different ways for different cases...  Going from Electric to Hydro has been an interesting experience.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-09-29**:
Yes, it's a difficult migration. Once it's done, the catkin/bloom-only world works reasonably smoothly.

**Comment by [sam26](https://answers.ros.org/users/29143/sam26/) on 2017-03-06**:
"Yes, rospack does only traverse the run dependencies" - Doesn't `rospack depends` list out all the ros dependencies of that package ( both build and run, from what I have checked using the package actionlib ) and only excludes the system dependencies?